# using @media to create mobile friendly website - super wide page with blank right side issue edit: ADDED IMAGE

Tags: html, css, wordpress

[juniorgoldreport.com](http://juniorgoldreport.com) is the website I'm working with. On regular desktop view its fine, when I shrink the window down smaller and smaller it seems to act responsive and it's progress. It is being made in wordpress.

When I view it on my smartphone, (LG G4), there is a huge white space to the right of the website and I cannot figure out why. I've been using inspect element via chrome to trouble shoot, but being on a cell phone I dont have that option so easily.

Does anyone have an idea?

Here's an image of the issue when you search the website on a mobile device:
[image: extra white space]

Along with that too, if you guys easily know in my header my logo and my social media/subscribe button are really difficult to align center so its even on both side and they're aligned vertically.Any hints or ideas on this one? I'm much more concerned with the mobile issue though.

Comment: I don't know if this has anything to do with it, but there is content at the bottom of the page that has a left positioning of 50px (probably about the same gap as the gap on the right for the top content), and the device could be including this in the viewport calculation.

Comment: I see what you mean and I'm not sure if that's it. I'll play with that and see if it does anything. 

It seems to me as the white space is almost the same size as the entire website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to me like it's

```
.page { overflow: visible !important; }
```

in line 3308 that's causing the issue. Not sure what purpose that's serving, so you can take it out, but it might cause other issues.

Comment: thank you. I'll take a look at this as well.
The reason It's in here is because on certain pages it puts an extra scrolling bar so I used that to remove it.

Comment: this was the solution. I made it overflow:hidden and everything was glorious. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Remove `left: 50px;` from `.site-main .sidebar-container` and the gap should disappear.

Comment: Testing it in Firebug resolved it for me.  Using `overflow: hidden;` will remove anything from "spilling over" but doesn't actually solve your problem with identifying the culprit.

Comment: I'm not sure then. I removed the left: 50px and viewing it from my mobile it didn't change it then when I went on my desktop the website in general was a mess. The left: 50px I realized kept the main content and sidebar seperate (creating a white space)

Comment: Well you can add a media query to override that specific piece of CSS.  I would just hate to see your content get cut-off when it doesn't have to be.

Comment: Something like this `@media screen and (max-width:699px) { .site-main .sidebar-container { left: auto !important;  padding: 20px !important; } }`